# Adding GoDaddy Domain name in Azure CDN endpoint

Tags: dns, godaddy, cdn, cname, azure

I am trying to map my custom domain purchased from GoDaddy to Azure CDN endpoint. I tried documentation steps from here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain
But still Azure website says that DNS record is not available. See below Azure CDN domain name settings and Go Daddy settings I am using.
Did anyone faced such issues before.
[image: Azure CDN settings]
[image: Go Daddy Settings]

Comment: Hi Vaibhav, and welcome! What part of your domain are you trying to map to Azure? Are you trying to get `www.example.com` and `example.com` to map to Azure, as in a standard website setup, or are you only trying to do a subdomain? Your DNS records seem maybe conflicted, as they are trying to point both to Azure and to GoDaddy's domain parking service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's looks you are created `www.example.com.example.com` instead `www.example.com` CNAME. You should change `@` to azure edge CNAME domain.
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It worked.